# Issue with UISearchBar frame

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UITableView` which I programatically create and I have added a `UISearchBar`/`UISearchDisplayController` as a subview. It looks like this:

[image]

That's all fine but when I touch it to invoke searching the frames changes strangely, any idea why?

[image]

I've tried manually setting the frame, doesn't seem to help.

The `UITableView` is a property of a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a duplicate of this question [UIsearchBar. Can't change frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025982/uisearchbar-cant-change-frame).

The answer being that you can't mess with UISearchBar's frame.

Comment: Wow, I'm really quite surprised at that! but hey, at least now I know!